# PDO -> bindParam() does not bind variable to PDO -> prepare() statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am trying to build a small search tool for a single table of a mySQL Database.
Sadly i can't bind my function parameter to my sql statement and i can't figure out why.

This is how i think it works.(maybe you can spot a mistake in my general approach)

1. At first the parameter ($field) get passed to the function by referencing it inside the function call at the bottom of the file.
2. I am referencing the paramter key of $field (:field) inside the $dbh->prepare() statement.
3. The variable $field is bound as a Parameter with $query->bindParam()
4. The query is being executed
5. $field is used to extract the title from the modified query.

I already figured out that the problem only occurs when i try to bind the parameter to the statement. So somewhere between step 2-4.

Whenever i insert the $field as a pure string (as "title" into step 2+5) everythings works fine. But thats not very dynamic and therefore i can't use the functions parameter.

Is there someone out there who could give me a hint :) ?
I am thankfull for any help.

```
<?php
// establish connection to database
$dbh = new PDO($server, $user, $pass);

/* function takes PDO object and a string that defines the column of our table that is supposed to be returned */
function searchField($dbh,$field){

    if(isset($_POST['searchbar'])){

        $searchInput = $_POST['searchbar'];
        $searchInput = "%" . $searchInput . "%";
        // (2)
        $query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM docs WHERE :field LIKE :searchInput');
        // (3)
        $query->bindParam(':field',$field);
        $query->bindParam(':searchInput',$searchInput);
        // (4)            
        $query->execute();

        foreach ($query as $doc){
            // (5)
            return $doc[$field];

        }




    }

}
```

?>

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" class="search-form">
    <div class="searchbar-container">
       <input class="searchbar" name="searchbar" placeholder="Enter a filename..."></input>
       <button class="btn btn-default search-button " type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search submit-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </div>
</form>


<div class="result-title-container">
    <?php

        // (1) ==== The function call ==== 

        echo "<h4>" . searchField($dbh,"title") . "</h4>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`bindParam` can only bind **values**, not object names (a column, in your case) or syntactic elements. If you want to dynamically set the name of the column before the `like` operator, you'd have to resort to string manipulation:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM docs WHERE $field LIKE :searchInput');
$query->bindParam(':searchInput',$searchInput);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I rearranged my code but i am not sure if i'm creating any security issues.

`php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM docs WHERE ' . $field . ' LIKE :searchInput';

            $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            //$query->bindParam(':field',$field);
            $query->bindParam(':searchInput',$searchInput);
            $query->execute();`

Comment: @Landocal: Depends where `$field` is coming from.  If it's hard-coded in the PHP as you show, then it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
In this case $field is declared inside the program (as a string based parameter)  and not by the user.
(see step 5)
I guess in this case its not a problem ?